# NGINX: user not found in .htpasswd

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to protect my website with authentication. This is my `nginx.conf`:

```
server {

  listen 7200;

  sendfile on;

  auth_basic "Restricted";
  auth_basic_user_file conf/.htpasswd;

  default_type application/octet-stream;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   1100;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;


  root /usr/share/nginx/html;


  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  location /index.html {
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    expires 0;
    try_files /index.html =404;
  }

}
```

And this is my `.htpasswd`:

```
test:{SHA}MksaHGWazm3b5BrE2CPJvAQU8tk=
martha:{PLAIN}5fx/FG1a
Carmina:{PLAIN}test
mika:{PLAIN}sd5r-r
```

However, if i try to access the website, NGINX continues asking me username/password. This is my server log:

```
2022/10/04 10:14:22 [error] 7#7: *1 user "Carmina" was not found in "/etc/nginx/conf/.htpasswd", client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:7200"
```

The `.htpasswd` file exists and is located correctly because i can `cat` it.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed "apache2-utils"?? Maybe try following this: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/